# How can create a custom button for GeolocateControl in react-map-gl

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

I am using `react-map-gl` to show my map component and I wanna have a custom button to locate user on his location; I'm using `GeolocateControl` component but and I got `display: 'none'` to its default button and for another button's `onClick` event I call this `geoControlRef.current.trigger()`; For the first time I call that shows the user location correctly but for next clicks it show wrong locations that are not my current location. what is the problem?

```
const onCurrentLocationClick = () => {
    geoControlRef?.current?.trigger()
  }
```

```
<GeolocateControl
              ref={geoControlRef}
              fitBoundsOptions={{
                zoom: 16,
              }}
              showAccuracyCircle={false}
              style={{ display: 'none' }}
              showUserHeading
            />
            <div className="absolute bottom-4 right-4 z-ultra">
              <CircularButton mode="primary" size="medium" onClick={onCurrentLocationClick} icon={locationButtonIcon} />
            </div>
          </>
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue you're encountering might be related to the behavior of the GeolocateControl component from react-map-gl. When you call the trigger() method of the GeolocateControl to initiate the user location request, it might take a bit of time to retrieve the accurate location. If you're triggering it rapidly in succession, it could be using cached or previously fetched locations, leading to the behavior you're seeing.

One way to address this issue is to ensure that the GeolocateControl is not triggered too frequently. You could implement a debounce mechanism to delay calling trigger() and give enough time for the user's location to be accurately determined before attempting another request.

Here's an example of how you might implement a debounce function using JavaScript:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { GeolocateControl } from 'react-map-gl';
import CircularButton from './CircularButton'; // Import your CircularButton component

const MapComponent = () => {
  const geoControlRef = useRef();
  let debounceTimeout = null;

  const onCurrentLocationClick = () => {
    // Clear previous timeouts
    clearTimeout(debounceTimeout);

    // Debounce the trigger using a timeout
    debounceTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      geoControlRef?.current?.trigger();
    }, 1000); // Adjust the debounce delay as needed
  };

  return (
    <>
      <GeolocateControl
        ref={geoControlRef}
        fitBoundsOptions={{
          zoom: 16,
        }}
        showAccuracyCircle={false}
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        showUserHeading
      />
      <div className="absolute bottom-4 right-4 z-ultra">
        <CircularButton mode="primary" size="medium" onClick={onCurrentLocationClick} icon={locationButtonIcon} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

the onCurrentLocationClick function is debounced using a timeout. The debounce timeout is cleared before setting a new one, ensuring that the trigger() method is only called after a specified delay, which gives enough time for the location accuracy to be determined.

Adjust the debounce delay (in milliseconds) based on your needs. This approach should help prevent rapid consecutive calls to trigger() and ensure that you're getting accurate user location updates.